# Exclude double quotes (") from being turned into &#34;

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, ascii, special-characters

Don't know if this has been answered yet, but I'll give it a shot.

Supposedly I have a string like this:

```
var x = '&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning';
```

And i use `.replace()` to turn the special characters to ASCII, like so:

```
x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

It will appear as:

```
&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning
```

But I want it to print as:

```
"Hello" &amp; good morning
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you "print" it? Do you output it in HTML?

Comment: How you're using `x` variable

Comment: I don't see the part of code which does the replace for special characters. The one you have is for replacing lines.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev No, I `console.log()` it.

Comment: You don't describe the full problem.  Your string `x` will not show as `&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning` in most contexts.  If it is showing that way, then you need to describe exactly what you did to make it show that way.  What did you do to `x`?

Comment: @Growlithe Your `replace` does not convert characters to HTML. You do it somewhere else. Can you the whole code from the declaration of `x` and until you `console.log` it?

Comment: Your regex is only deleting `\n` and `\r` from the string, and doing nothing else. <br> `var x = '"Hello" & good morning';
x=x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
console.log(x)`
Output is `"Hello" & good morning`

Comment: FYI, if you just do `console.log(x)`, it shows as it should [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/b7r46vob/) so we really have no idea where you're getting `&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning` from.

Comment: Alright I messed up the question. Let me edit it first.

Comment: Edited. The string already has the ascii codes in the first place. What I want to do is make all the other special characters into ascii EXCEPT the double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try following snippet:
Input: `'&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning';`
Output: `"Hello" &amp; good morning`

```js
var x = '&#34;Hello&#34; &amp; good morning';
var decodeHtmlEntity = function(x) {
  return x.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
};
alert(decodeHtmlEntity(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
   var x = '\"Hello\" & good morning';
x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

}
```

Comment: I can't touch the variable. That was just an example. The text that will be replaced will be user-defined. So what if the user decides to put in double quotes.

Comment: hello is constant over there you are defining it?

Comment: Not getting what you are trying to say because the code you have send it is working fine in w3schools haven't did any change the text you are giving taking that in div and then fetching in js with innerhtml its working....plz xpln what you need

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").replace(/&#34;/g, '"');
```

And I almost missed it. Thanks for those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises for example when exporting in flask-python or ninja-python `render_template('./mytemp.html',var_1 =' "hello" ')` a variable `var_1` to your html template `mytemp.html`, so that in the html the double quotes appears as &#34 when substituting `{{var_1}}`, i.e. `&#34hello&#34`. If this is your case, this can be subsaned simply using the `safe` operator in your html template mytemp.html (of course inside javascript),

```
var myvar = {{var_1 | safe}}
```

As simple as that.